# Label text not changing during timer tick

Tags: c#, winforms

I have scripted a program that gets a raw announcement from a website and puts it into a text called "announcements". However, the text doesn't change at all even though there are 0 errors.

```
namespace hidden
{
    public partial class dashboard : Form
    {
        public dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Timer timer1;

        public void InitTimer()
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = 10000;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        string url = "hidden";
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            announcement.Text = webclient.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you calling `InitTimer()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jimi said, you need to actually call the `InitTimer` method.  You could add it to the form's constructor:

```
    public dashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitTimer();
    }
```

Calling it in the constructor will work fine, but it will slow down the constructor to take a while, and the timer will be ticking even though the form isn't visible, and nobody can see what it is doing.

I think the better approach would be to add it to the `dashboard_load` event handler.  This it will start updating as soon as the form is visible.

Depending on the lifecycle of your app, you will probably want to stop the timer somehow.  You could call `Timer.Stop()` in the `dashboard_closing` handler if you like.